# How to generate multiple pytest tests with different parameterizations?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I would want something like this:

```
def _test_X(
    fixture_a: A,
    fixture_b: B
) -> None:
   pass

test_X_with_param_1 = pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_a', ['A1'], indirect=True)(_test_X)
test_X_with_param_2 = pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_a', ['A2'], indirect=True)(_test_X)
```

I want to do this in order to easily run all tests with `param_2` or all tests with `param_1` using pytest's `-k` option. I would rarely want to run the tests with `param_1` and `param_2` together. However, when I try to run the test I get a error like

```
test.runfiles/pypi__36__pytest_5_4_3/_pytest/python.py", line 787, in _checkargnotcontained
    raise ValueError("duplicate {!r}".format(arg))
ValueError: duplicate 'fixture_a'
```

One alternative that works is

```
def _test_X(
    fixture_a: A,
    fixture_b: B
) -> None:
   pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_a', ['A1'], indirect=True)
def test_X_with_param_1(
    fixture_a: A,
    fixture_b: B
) -> None:
   _test_X(fixture_a, fixture_b)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_a', ['A2'], indirect=True)
def test_X_with_param_2(
    fixture_a: A,
    fixture_b: B
) -> None:
   _test_X(fixture_a, fixture_b)
```

but this is somewhat verbose and requires updating multiple places if the args to `_test_X` ever need to be changed. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi, in your alternative, aren't you doing twice the same thing? Also, what is the value for fixture_b?

Comment: Thanks @Laurent, I updated the code in the alternative. Also, fixture_b is not paramaterized, it's just a normal fixture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several input values with the [pytest.mark.parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) decorator, like this:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_a', ['A1', 'A2'], indirect=True)
def test_X_with_params(
    fixture_a: A,
    fixture_b: B
) -> None:
   _test_X(fixture_a, fixture_b)
```

And then, from the command line, you can run one test:

```sh
pytest . -k "test_X_with_params[A1]"
```

Or the other:

```sh
pytest . -k "test_X_with_params[A2]"
```